# How to efficiently search a JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

The following code works fine:

```
var stores = new Array();
stores[0] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "001", Qty: "1", OH: "1" };
stores[1] = { ItemNumber: "2002", Code: "002", Qty: "3", OH: "2" };
stores[2] = { ItemNumber: "2003", Code: "003", Qty: "5", OH: "8" };
stores[3] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "004", Qty: "10", OH: "90" };

var item = "2001";
var code = "001";

var searchResult = jQuery.grep(stores, function (store, indexInArray) {
    var found = false;
    if (item != "" && code != "") {
        found = (store.Code == code) && (store.ItemNumber == item);
    }
    else if (item != "" && code == "") {
        found = (store.ItemNumber == item);
    }
    else if (code != "" && item == "") {
        found = (store.Code == code);
    }
    return found;
});

$.each(searchResult, function (index, obj) {
    console.log("found: " + obj.Code);
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hwpnbkm3/

However I am not really happy with the code, because there are way too many if/else statements. Also if I wanted to search by Qty or OH, then it will get even more complicated. Is there a way to search through this array without the multiple if/else statements? Can I maybe build a dynamic query to search through the array?

Comment: you've got 3 conditions you're checking for, therefore you need 3 conditionals, which you've got. if you want fewer ifs(), then reduce the number of conditions you're checking for.

Comment: I understand that. But the real question is if we can somehow create the search criteria dynamically.

Comment: But if I add more searchable properties to the array, then the entire if/else code will become messy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: not with grep. you'd have to write JS code and eval() it if you want to dynamically create the function grep is using for the comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function could be simplified to:

```
return (item == "" || store.ItemNumber == item) &&
       (code == "" || store.Code == code) &&
       (item != "" || code != "");
```

But what I would recommend instead is this: Instead of having individual variables for your query, make an object.

```
var stores = new Array();
stores[0] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "001", Qty: "1", OH: "1" };
stores[1] = { ItemNumber: "2002", Code: "002", Qty: "3", OH: "2" };
stores[2] = { ItemNumber: "2003", Code: "003", Qty: "5", OH: "8" };
stores[3] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "004", Qty: "10", OH: "90" };

var query = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "001" };

var searchResult = jQuery.grep(stores, function (store, indexInArray) {
    var found = false;
    for(var n in query) {
      if(query[n] != "") {
        if(query[n] != store[n]) {
          found = false;
          break;
        }
        found = true;
      }
    }
    return found;
});

$.each(searchResult, function (index, obj) {
    console.log("found: " + obj.Code);
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Let me try that and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Note that this code was written in such a way to preserve the semantics of your original code. I would recommend not including a search term in the search object if it is blank so that you can then eliminate the `if(query[n] != "")`

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass an object as the search query?

```
var stores = new Array();
stores[0] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "001", Qty: "1", OH: "1" };
stores[1] = { ItemNumber: "2002", Code: "002", Qty: "3", OH: "2" };
stores[2] = { ItemNumber: "2003", Code: "003", Qty: "5", OH: "8" };
stores[3] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "004", Qty: "10", OH: "90" };

var query = {
  ItemNumber: '2001',
  Code: '004'
}

var searchResult = jQuery.grep(stores, function (store, indexInArray) {
    var matched = false;
    for (var prop in query) {
      if (store[prop] && store[prop] == query[prop]) {
        matched = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return matched;
});

for (var matched in searchResult) {
  console.log("Item matched:" + matched);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3axqktnn/

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it up a bit like this:

```
var searchResult = jQuery.grep(stores, function (store, indexInArray) {
    if(typeof item !=='undefined' && item.length>0 && typeof code !=='undefined' && code.length>0)
        return store.ItemNumber==item &&store.Code==code;
    else
        return typeof item !== 'undefined' && item.length>0 ? store.ItemNumber==item : store.Code==code;
});
```

Fiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/hwpnbkm3/3/

It checks for the two variables, if they are undefined or empty strings, then it will only check the defined one.

If you wanted to add more parameters, you would need to pass in an object: http://jsfiddle.net/hwpnbkm3/4/

```
var search={
    ItemNumber:"2001",
    Code:"AA1",
    OH:1
};

var searchResult = jQuery.grep(stores, function (store, indexInArray) {
    var found=true;
    for (var i in search){
        if(search[i]!=store[i]){
            found=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
});
```

I am not sure how you set up, but you would need extra checks to make sure that the search field is not null and that the store field exists.  So you will need to add some extra error checking depending on your set up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use `underscorejs` or `lodash` instead

http://underscorejs.org/#where

Answer (score 0):

```
var stores = new Array();
stores[0] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "001", Qty: "1", OH: "1" };
stores[1] = { ItemNumber: "2002", Code: "002", Qty: "3", OH: "2" };
stores[2] = { ItemNumber: "2003", Code: "003", Qty: "5", OH: "8" };
stores[3] = { ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "004", Qty: "10", OH: "90" };

// Consider the object to be searched for.

var search = {ItemNumber: "2001", Code: "001", Qty: "1", OH: "1"};
// Based on your code above.
for(i=0;i<stores.length;i++)
{
    // iterate the objects in store, get their keys.
    var found = true;
    var keys = Object.keys(stores[i]);
    for(j =0;j<keys.length;j++)
    {   // iterate the keys and check if their value matches to the search object   
        var key = keys[j];
        var value = stores[i][key];
        found = found && (value == search[key]);
    }
   if(found) break;
}
```